# Detect if browser uses GPU accelerated graphics for render

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-4, gpu, mozilla

So I'm building large size site, which uses css3 transitions for animations (I'm using jaquery.transit to manipulate element transitions and their css styles). And I stumbled upon 2 problems:

1. FF (latest update) doesn't use GPU for translate3d() layer rendering, maybe I'm wrong and mozilla doesn't use GPU accelerated graphics at all. I really don't understand that completely yet.
2. Even if I trick for example Chrome in using GPU for translate3d() and translateZ() layer rendering, on computers with bad GPU or with no GPU those graphics are so terrible you sometimes can't even see middle of transition just start and end.

**Questions:**

1. What do I do to improve FPS for transitioning elements, e.g. I have 3200x3200 `div` rotating and scaling and translating in x,y axis at same time, with approx. 5-20 elements displayed on that `div's` surface?
2. Maybe there is a way I can detect if browser has enough GPU support to know if I need to redirect to simpler version of site or not?

Comment: A 3200x3200px element is *massive*. I imagine most GPUs would struggle to throw that around in memory. Can you try the same effect on something smaller and see if you get the same performance problems?

Comment: @OllyHodgson well you see, I need that big territory. You see my territory is 3200x3200 big, but my viewport is 1024x750. I know games render only view area, but I have no clue how to do that or wetter it's even possible. And to answer your question, with smaller and lesser object it renders smoothly.

Comment: Can you keep the div smaller and scale it as needed with CSS media queries?

Comment: @Mooseman how do you suggest I do that?

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ for using Media Queries. Just beware of browser compatibility (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)

Comment: @Mooseman as I understand with media queries I can scale my content, but in my case the 3.2k x 3.2k size `div` can't be minimized to something like 1k x 1k resolution. The `div` purpose is to serve as ground floor for content on it. I guess my idea is bit ahead of time in HTML5 and css3, because only top end machines can render my content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue at the time was that all of the PNG's on the screen had to recalculated and recompiled in the browser.

There were several things I had to do to to maximize performance:

1. Always have predefined `width` and `height` attributes on images. What this does is let's the browser know what size the picture should be and when used together with `scale()` it won't recalculate and recompile those images. These things were very expensive. So basically if nothing else than `scale()` modified image size, everything was perfect and animations were awesome.
2. Wherever possible avoid using `visibility` property, it literally acts like `opacity: 0` keeping the element in the layout making layout recalculation much longer. Always where possible use `display: none`, this will completely eliminate element from the layout calculations. This was a major pitfall, because I had to re-think the UI to exclude `visibility` and I had to minimize used DOM node count.

Overall it was a huge adventure and big experience, hope this question/answer helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Because [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) uses GPU, the amazing `Modernizr` project permits to check that for webGL supported browsers: http://modernizr.com/news/

Check `Modernizr.webgl` under http://modernizr.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I need to know if browsers GPU can actually be capable to normally render my transitions. It says Firefox supports WebGL, but problem is that it renders my transitions worse then chrome. And next thing is, if I have a browser that uses GPU for rendering, I want to know if browsers GPU has enough power or something that could tell me that it will have bad performance rendering layers.